# Angularjs: alternate solution of <iframe> to render files from server

Tags: angularjs

I need to render HTML file from server in my application which is built using Angular. I display table of contents in the left nav and need to render HTML file at the right side on click of each file in left nav. In summary i have following three block in my application.

1. Left nav to render Table of Contents. 
   I have used angular directive to render table of contents where data is coming from server in json format.
2. In the right side; i at the top need to render HTML file coming from server.
3. In the right side; at bottom I use angular directive to render the list of comments.

For #2; I am not sure if i should use `<iframe>` or I have any other solution as well. Following image can help to explain my requirement.

[image]

Looking for advice. Please ignore if this is silly query.

Comment: explain `render html file` in more detail. Is it full page with scripts needed? Can scripts and css be run in angular app page also? Is it just one page, or many pages depending on user choices.  Does other page need to interact with angular scope ? Not enough details given.

Comment: Yes. CSS needs to run on file which needs to load. This file can also have images embedded etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you have in mind? [Live demo here (click)](http://plnkr.co/edit/FOrLFGDNM3poLEBkkpmt?p=preview).

This has links in the left column that when clicked, will load the corresponding html file into the right column.

```
<div class="left">
  <p>Click a filename to display.</p>
  <a ng-repeat="file in files" ng-click="showFile(file)">{{file}}</a>
</div>
<div class="right">
  <div ng-include="current"></div>
</div>
```

and the js:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.files = [
    'foo.html',
    'bar.html',
    'baz.html'
  ];

  $scope.current = $scope.files[0];

  $scope.showFile = function(file) {
    $scope.current = file;
  }
});
```

Comment: In terms of requirement yes. On click of these link i want to display content there itself.

Comment: @DilipKumar I don't understand what you're saying... The contents of the html file is displayed. If you're looking for something else, please be more clear.

Comment: I am sorry for confusion question. I have added screenshot of my requirement. I want that user can click on file from list and file should display at right side. Hope it explain. And to accomplish it i don't want to use <iframe>

Comment: @DilipKumar I don't know how you're missing this, but look at the red div http://plnkr.co/edit/FOrLFGDNM3poLEBkkpmt?p=preview I can't make it more clear that the file contents are being loaded on the right side.

Comment: Thanks. I got your solution now. Looks this is what I was looking for. Going to integrate with my application.